# Trouble selecting specific items using Sanity.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I am new to both Sanity and React, so I apologize beforehand if this is a silly question, but I am having troubles to retrieve a specific item from a Sanity schema.

I am trying to achieve this visuals for a menu-like purpose.
[Goal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Km97.jpg)

I started by creating a scheme that looks like this as well as populating it with the corresponding images.
[Sanity schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DBS4.png)
But I can't figure out how to call an specific image. Ej. Melaminas or Herrajes, or Cubiertas, etc

This is the code for my table in which I have only managed to use the first image in the dataset which apparently is called by default.

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from "next/link";
import { urlFor } from '../lib/client';
import useScript from '../hooks/useScript';

const HomeGrid = ({category}) => {
  return (
        <div className="d-block w-75 mx-auto">
            <div className="row">

                <div className="col-sm">
                    <div className="grid-container">
                        <img 
                            src={urlFor(category.image)} 

                            className="d-block w-100" 
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="col-sm">
                    <div className="col-sm">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="grid-container">
                                <img 
                                    src={urlFor(category.image)}  
                                    className="d-block w-100"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm">
                                <div className="grid-container-small">
                                    Herrajes
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm">
                                <div className="grid-container-small">
                                    Maderas
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>           
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomeGrid
```

Outputting this
[Current output layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLCC5.jpg)

What is the best way to call my images by "category"? Thanks to anybody that is able to help :)

UPDATE
I'm [fetching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ic2o.png) the info in my index and then calling my grid document like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXgVZ.png)

Here is the complete index.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import {client} from '../lib/client';
import { Product,FooterBanner,HeroBanner,Carousel,HomeGrid} from '../components';
import useScript from '../hooks/useScript';

const Inicio = ({products,bannerData,galleryData,categoryData}) => {

  return (
    <>  
        <Carousel gallery={galleryData && galleryData[0] } />
        <div className='products-heading'>
            <h2>Explora Nuestros Productos</h2>
            <p>¡Y si no los tenemos los conseguimos!</p>
        </div>

        <HomeGrid category={categoryData && categoryData[0]} />

        <div className='products-heading'>
            <h2>Lo Más Vendido</h2>
            <p>¡A los mejores precios!</p>
        </div>

        <div className='products-container mx-auto '>
          {products?.map((product) => <Product key={product._id} product={product} />)}
        </div>
        
        <HeroBanner heroBanner={bannerData.length && bannerData[0] } />
        <FooterBanner />
    </>
  )
}



export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  
  const query = '*[_type == "product"]';
  const products = await client.fetch(query);
  const bannerQuery = '*[_type == "banner"]';
  const bannerData = await client.fetch(bannerQuery);
  const galleryQuery = '*[_type == "gallery"]';
  const galleryData = await client.fetch(galleryQuery);
  const categoryQuery = '*[_type == "category"]';
  const categoryData = await client.fetch(categoryQuery);

  return{
    props: {products, bannerData, galleryData,categoryData, }
  }
}
export default Inicio
```

Comment: When querying for the `category` document, you are supposed to receive an array of objects with all the categories but it seems like you are only passing one individual category item to `HomeGrid` via `props`. Can you include in your question where are you fetching the `category` document and passing the `props` to `HomeGrid`?

Comment: Me da mucha pena, ya vi el problema en el index en donde solo mando el categoryData[0], dejé  <HomeGrid category={categoryData]} /> y funcionó :)

Comment: Seleccionando de esta manera src={urlFor(category[X].image)} donde X es la categoría que deseo

Comment: Indeed, you are passing just the first item via `props`. To achieve what you want, `HomeGrid` should have access to all categories, so just pass them all to it and access each one of them via their index or just destructure the array.